# Subquery returned more than 1 value in update

Tags: sql

I'm trying to assign territories based on states. In the RepAssign table there is only 1 record for each state.

```
update MasterList 
set T = (select Territory from RepAssign  )
from MasterList M
join RepAssign R on M.ST = R.State
```

I get the error: Subquery returned more than 1 value.

Comment: T is float and ur input val is nvarchar... cast it into float...

Comment: Why can't you `set T = R.Territory`? What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm a n00b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't you mean this:

```
update MasterList 
set T = R.Territory
from MasterList M
join RepAssign R on M.ST = R.State
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
update MasterList 
set T = (select Territory from RepAssign where state = MasterList.st)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update MasterList M, RepAssign R set T = R.Territory  where M.ST = R.State;
```